# Best way to doing this in php

Tags: php

I'm fetching data from database and suppose there is 23 columns in a table then I have to write 23 lines to set value.
Is there any other short way to do this?

In the example below there are only 15 columns and I wrote 15 lines. any short way?

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $export ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        $line.=setValue($row[0]);
        $line.=setValue($row[1]);
        $line.=setValue($row[2]);
        $line.=setValue($row[3]);
        $line.=setValue($row[4]);
        $line.=setValue($row[5]);
        $line.=setValue($row[6]);
        $line.=setValue($row[7]);
        $line.=setValue($row[8]);
        $line.=setValue($row[9]);
        $line.=setValue($row[10]);
        $line.=setValue($row[11]);
        $line.=setValue($row[12]);
        $line.=setValue($row[13]);
        $line.=setValue($row[14]);

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $value) {
        $line.=setValue($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure  if this is what you are looking for but you can use a for loop like this:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $export ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++)
        {
           $line.=setValue($row[$i]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $export ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
           $line .= setValue($row[$i]);
        }

    }
```

That's one approach. There are others. You can replace the '15' with a count form the returned array. This way the for loop will iterate until the end of the array.

Ups, lol, too late...

Comment: Using a fixed bound on the loop is messy - evaluating a count on each iteration is innefficent

Comment: $bound = sizeof($row);
for($i=0; $i < $bound; $i++)...
your way is better though ;)

Comment: What happen when there are more than 15 coluns?

Comment: @Shakti Singh: It was just an example... you can use the correction below or use other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

While you could do something like....

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($export)) {
   $line=array();
   $line=array_map('setValue',$xport);
   $line=implode('',$line);
}
```

....its a very messy construct - it presupposes that the query will return a very well defined resultset, and the structure of the resultset and its subsequent application are diplaced; as a general rule of thumb, you should never use mysql_fetch_array - use mysql_fetch_assoc instead.